# How does pessimistic locking work in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently using Hibernate 6 and H2. I want to safely increment `count` field of `Entity` class but using more then 1 thread per time just to make sure that transaction is actually locking my entity. But when I ran this code, result `count` column in H2 wasn't 10, but instead some random number under 10. What am I missing about pessimistic locking?

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            Session innerSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction innerTransaction = innerSession.beginTransaction();
            Entity entity = innerSession.get(Entity.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

            entity.setCount(entity.getCount() + 1);

            innerSession.flush();
            innerTransaction.commit();
            innerSession.close();
        });

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            Session innerSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction innerTransaction = innerSession.beginTransaction();
            Entity entity = innerSession.get(Entity.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

            entity.setCount(entity.getCount() + 1);

            innerSession.flush();
            innerTransaction.commit();
            innerSession.close();
        });
}
```

Entire method:

```
Long id;
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;
Transaction transaction;
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Properties properties = new Properties();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

properties.put(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.USER, "root");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.PASS, "root");
properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, H2Dialect.class.getName());
properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, true);
properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, Action.CREATE.getExternalHbm2ddlName());

// classes are provided by another library
entityClasses.forEach(configuration::addAnnotatedClass);

sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(properties).build());
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

// initial value of count field is 0
id = (Long) session.save(new Entity());

transaction.commit();

for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            Session innerSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction innerTransaction = innerSession.beginTransaction();
            Entity entity = innerSession.get(Entity.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

            entity.setCount(entity.getCount() + 1);

            innerSession.flush();
            innerTransaction.commit();
            innerSession.close();
        });

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            Session innerSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction innerTransaction = innerSession.beginTransaction();
            Entity entity = innerSession.get(Entity.class, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

            entity.setCount(entity.getCount() + 1);

            innerSession.flush();
            innerTransaction.commit();
            innerSession.close();
        });
}

executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

session.clear(); // prevent reading from cache
System.out.println(session.get(Entity.class, id).getCount()); // printed result doesn't match 10, same for reading from H2 browser interface
session.close();
```

Comment: what H2 version are you on? https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1759

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I'm using 1.4.200, but I will upgrade to higher version, maybe it will help

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov version upgrade didn't help

Comment: Just tried, can't reproduce on `1.4.200` and `1.4.197`. `1.4.198` is definitely buggy. Would you mind providing the whole method body and how you verify that `count` has wrong value - doing that right after `for loop` is not correct, because executorService might not finished processing tasks.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov edited question, check it pls.

Comment: log exceptions,

Comment: @Antoniossss there are no exceptions, only incorrect `count` value.

Comment: You are not logging them if there are any - which could explain incorrect count. Wrap  your runnable blocks with try-catch. Most probabl you will see pessimistic locking exceptions of some sort.

Comment: @Antoniossss if there were any exception I would see it in output, there is no need to wrap anything in try-catch. There are no exceptions in my case.

Comment: @zexed640 I created a sample project based on your question. I see PessimisticLockException exception  - INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command
org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select s1_0.count from Subjects s1_0 where s1_0.count=? for update]

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian what version of Hibernate and H2 are you using?

Comment: Hibernate core version is 6.1.1.Final, H2 version 1.4.197

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian your test case is irrelevant: you use count as PK and mutate it, thus you are getting exception because query does not return rows.

Comment: @zexed640 I would agree with @Antoniossss - try to write test case in more accurate way or analyse output more thoroughly (would you mind providing output (SQL statements, bind variables, results) as well?). Basic idea: if it is required to get the most recent state of data, there are two patterns to do that: "lock and refresh" or `select * from ... where id = ? for update`, HBN actually should prefer the second one, if not - that is HBN issue, otherwise - DB's, another reason - not all tasks got executed due to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simple, I need just to upgrade version of hibernate to [6.0.0.Alpha9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha9). Higher versions requires 11 java to compile (I'm using 8). Seems like it was a bug in [6.0.0.Alpha6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha6), which I used previously. There was no problem with H2 [1.4.200](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2/1.4.200). From hibernate sql logs I understood that the main problem in [6.0.0.Alpha6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha6) was incorrect `select` query for transaction with pessimistic lock, it was just regular `select`, but in [6.0.0.Alpha9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha9) already used `select for update`, which prevents other transactions from reading this row.